# Tkinter Entry not showing the current value of textvariable

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Consider this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

tk=Tk()

def sub():
    var=StringVar(value='default value')

    def f(): pass

    Entry(tk,textvariable=var).pack()
    Button(tk,text='OK',command=f).pack()

sub()
mainloop()
```

We expect the value of `var` appears in the entry, but actually it doesn't.

[image: nothing in the entry]

The weird thing is that if I put the statement `var.get()` in the callback function of the button, the value of `var` will apear.

[image: the value appeared]

Is that a bug caused by some kind of local variable optimization in Python? And what can I do to make sure that the value of `textvariable` will always appear in the entry?

Please execuse me for my poor English.

Comment: There's a solution to this problem, but you might want to consider _not_ using a `StringVar`; they are rarely needed. You can get and set the value via methods on the widget itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's getting garbage collected.

You can just get rid of the function (you also shouldn't nest functions like this)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

tk=Tk()

var=StringVar(value="default value")
Entry(tk, textvariable=var).pack()
Button(tk,text='OK').pack()

mainloop()
```

Or, if you want to keep the function.. set the stringvar as an attribute of tk or make it global.

Making it global:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

tk=Tk()
var = StringVar(value="Default value")

def sub():

    Entry(tk, textvariable=var).pack()
    Button(tk,text='OK').pack()

sub()
mainloop()
```

As an attribute of tk:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

tk=Tk()

def sub():

    tk.var = StringVar(value="Default value")
    Entry(tk, textvariable=tk.var).pack()
    Button(tk,text='OK').pack()

sub()
mainloop()
```